# Laravel 5 Project in Aptana

Tags: laravel-5, aptana

I just imported a Laravel 5 project but Aptana keeps finding syntax errors in half the php files.

Does anyone know why?

PS. already tried to set the PHP version to 5.4.x in the Project properties -> PHP Development. It keeps jumping back to 5.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a file 
"PATH_TO_PROJECT/.settings/com.aptana.editor.php.prefs" with the following content:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
phpVersion=php5.4
```